# How to get the binary image from webcam in Javascript PHP

Tags: php, javascript, webcam

I am an novice in Javascript and PHP. I am working on to create a visitor management system where a web form is used to insert the data and when clicked on Submit button data are stored in the database and a pass is printed. But my problem is that I am trying to use a web cam to take the snap of the visitor and want to save it in the database as BLOB. I don't have any idea but tried http://www.xarg.org/project/jquery-webcam-plugin/ etc and couldn't find any clue. Kindly help.

Comment: Can you tell what went wrong with jQuery webcam plugin?  The description on that page looks reasonable and it seems to do what you want.

Comment: I just coudn't find out how to get the binary and post it to the database. Kindly help with description, I am jaust a novice in the field.

Comment: Post your code, tell us where exactly you are stuck, ask a specific question and we will be able to help.

Comment: [this page](http://www.dynamsoft.com/Demo/Webcam/online_demo_Webcam.aspx) demos how to take a snap and then upload the image to a database.